# How do detect if Travis-Ci or not

Tags: travis-ci

I need a way to determine if the person calling the function is Travis-CI or not. If it is Travis-CI, I do not want to start a session here.
Right now, I have my tests script create a file called `test.txt` and then look for it.

```
protected function __construct() {
    if ( (!session_id()) && (!file_exists('test.txt' ))) session_start();
}
```

However, there has to be a better way. It seems, that without the file check, if there is in fact a session made, a new one will not be created. But this is not the case. If this was the case, the before link below should have passed.

[Before](https://travis-ci.org/#!/chriscct7/jigoshop/builds/2859226) the addition of the "test.txt" file: 
[After](https://travis-ci.org/#!/chriscct7/jigoshop/builds/2859424)

Comment: Systems that explicitly change their behaviour when being tested are **not** being tested properly.

Comment: @paxdiablo Not really. The issue at hand is that to test my wp plugin, we use a dependency which starts the session. Unfortunately, I can't turn that off.

Answer (score 58):

In general you can detect if you are on Travis-CI by checking the environment variables. You can check either for `CI=true` or the more specific `TRAVIS=true`. In PHP you can use the [`getenv()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) to get the value of an environment variable.

See the [complete list of the environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables). You can set even more [env variables in your .travis.yml](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/).

Comment: i believe that s a correct answer `CI=TRUE` is set, at least, for travis/appveyor/circleci.

Comment: That means: ```if( $_SERVER['CI'] === true ) { }```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JavaScript, there is a great module called [is-ci](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ci) which is available in NPM and is MIT Licensed.

Note: it gives `true` for any Continuous Integration environment, not only TravisCI.

Answer (score 0):

For Java i am checking the user:

```java
/**
 * check if we are in the Travis-CI environment
 * @return true if Travis user was detected
 */
public boolean isTravis() {
  String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
  return user.equals("travis");
}
```